# What is the meaning of the phrase "catch someone thinking"?

Tags: meaning

Here is the context:

> In a beginning, almost invariably, I’ll be interrupting the train of thought, **catching you thinking** while you are tempting to pay attention to the breath.

Comment: Tempting, or attempting?

Comment: Please please please don't quote something without giving the source of the quote. To do this is just rude.

Comment: This is broken English... "in a beginning"...

Comment: Sounds like some meditation video, poorly transcribed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use catch somebody when you discover someone doing something (often but not always doing something wrong)

> The teacher caught the girl smoking behind the bike shed.
>
> He caught me out shopping for his birthday present
>
> You should try to "catch your pupils doing good" and reward them for it.

The use in the quote is poetic and somewhat figurative. It suggests "discovering you doing something, and doing something that you want to remain hidden, because "thinking" is a private personal activity... I interrupted a private moment."